# Is there a setting on an HP P4014n printer to disable printing multiple copies?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

There's a shared printer that is getting abused by people printing tons of copies. I would like to restrict them to just 1 copy. I've looked into the "mopier" mode but I didn't seem to have luck with it. Does anyone know of a possible solution?

HP Laserjet P4014n

edit* what about active directory? I hadn't considered that at first

Comment: The setting is in the print properties menu, "Number of copies".  You're looking for a way to override a feature, which, I suspect, won't be a built-in feature.  The solution might be a human one rathen than software.

Answer (score 0):

IM are printer technical, and never see something, like you want...

i will recommend you, this software, is a printer counter, is free, and you can check the available options.

How to install a page counter on my printer
http://www.en.rellenadodecartuchos.com/2013/01/how-to-install-page-counter-for-my.html

im here if you need more help...

Comment: Please reread the question.  The problem is not counting pages, it's limiting print jobs to one copy regardless of the user's setting.

Comment: I said that installing the software you can consider the limitations for computers that can print.